# Why does the Franck-Condon matrix appear to not be unitary when written in the basis of phonon states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, open-quantum-systems, quantum-transport

**Preliminary:**  The Franck-Condon (FC) matrix can be defined as
\begin{align}
X & = e^{-x(b^{\dagger} - b)}, \label{eq: FC 1}
\end{align}
where $b^{\dagger}$ and $b$ are standard bosonic creation and annihilation operators defined via their action on a state filled with $q$ bosons:
\begin{align}
b^{\dagger} | q \rangle & = \sqrt{q+1} | q + 1 \rangle \\
b | q \rangle & = \sqrt{q} | q - 1 \rangle.
\end{align}
In this form, the FC matrix is regularly used in the description of molecular vibrational modes excited by electrons tunneling through an open quantum system; the bosons in this case are vibrational phonons. This also means that $x$ will contain some electron-phonon coupling and phonon frequency, but it is easier for my question to just leave it as some real number $x$.

**Question:** It appears, to me at least, that the FC matrix is unitary, $X^{\dagger} = X^{-1}$:
\begin{align}
X^{\dagger}X & = e^{x(b^{\dagger} - b)}e^{-x(b^{\dagger} - b)} = e^{(-x+x)(b^{\dagger} - b)} = I = XX^{\dagger},
\end{align}
where we can combine the exponentials because $b^{\dagger} - b$ commutes with itself. But I cannot see how to get the same result if I write the FC matrix in the orthonormal basis of phonon states. Here, and following well-established examples such as in *Many-particle physics* (1990) by Gerald D. Mahan, one can write
\begin{align}
\langle q | X | q' \rangle & = e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\min(q,q')!}{\max(q,q')!}}\left[\text{sgn}(q'-q)x\right]^{|q'-q|}L_{\min(q,q')}^{|q'-q|}(x^{2}) \\
\end{align}
where $L_{n}^{(k)}(x)$ are the generalized Laguerre polynomials. If I evaluate it for $x=1$ and a maximum phonon occupancy of $3$, for example, I get
\begin{align}
X & = \left[\begin{array}{c c c c} 
0.60653066 & 0.60653066 & 0.42888194 &  0.2476151 \\
-0.60653066 & 0. & 0.42888194 & 0.49523021 \\
0.42888194 & -0.42888194 & -0.30326533 & 0.17509032 \\
-0.2476151 & 0.49523021 & -0.17509032 & -0.40435377 \end{array}\right] \\
X^{\dagger} & = \left[\begin{array}{c c c c} 
0.60653066 & -0.60653066 & 0.42888194 &  -0.2476151 \\
0.60653066 & 0. & -0.42888194 & 0.49523021 \\
0.42888194 & 0.42888194 & -0.30326533 & -0.17509032 \\
0.2476151 & 0.49523021 & 0.17509032 & -0.40435377 \end{array}\right] \\
XX^{\dagger} & = \left[\begin{array}{c c c c} 
0.98101184 & -0.06131324 & -0.08671002 & -0.02503103 \\
-0.06131324 & 0.79707212 & -0.30348506 & -0.12515513 \\
-0.08671002 & -0.30348506 & 0.49050592 & -0.33629255 \\
-0.02503103 & -0.12515513 & -0.33629255 & 0.50072479
 \end{array}\right],
\end{align}
which evidently is not unitary. Am I missing something; is the FC matrix actually not unitary?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, almost as soon as I uploaded this I realized the problem; the orthonormal basis is technically infinite. As you increase the maximum phonon occupancy, the product $XX^{\dagger} \rightarrow I$. For example, with the maximum phonon occupancy at $20$, all elements for $i,j \leq 10$ follow $X_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$, but the other elements, especially for $i,j \geq 15$, do not.